# jQuery prop impacts performance in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, listbox

I have implemented a filter in Javascript for IE11, and other browsers. Basically when a key is pressed the matching options on a listbox will be activated according to their text. And the rest will be hidden.
This is my code so far:

```
function onkeyup(event) {
    searchKeyPress(this, 'actions_Options')
}

function searchKeyPress(input, listBoxId) {
    var value = $(input).val();
    if (value != "") {
        if (isIE()) {
            $("#" + listBoxId + " option").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#" + listBoxId + " option:contains(" + value + ")").prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $("#" + listBoxId + " option").hide();
            $("#" + listBoxId + " option:contains(" + value + ")").show();
        }
    } else {
        if (isIE()) {
            $("#" + listBoxId + " option").prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $("#" + listBoxId + " option").show();
        }
    }
}

function isIE() {
     return navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' || navigator.appName == 'Netscape';
}
```

Problem is when I start typing in IE11, it takes half a minute or so to disable the non-matching options, giving the feeling is not working, although it eventually disables them.

Comment: Why are you calling `isIE()` multiple times. Store its output in a variable and use it

Comment: Yeah, and group your `if()` instructions. Why make two identical `if()`s in a row? You could also cache `$("#" + listBoxId + " option")` in a variable

Comment: That's a good suggestion but doesn't really make a difference performance wise

Comment: The issue is not in this code, except if the `isIE()` function has an infinite loop or something.

Comment: I have added the isIE() function